# Required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, spring-repositories

I made some rest api's in my project. I have their models, repositories, controllers and services. They were working fine and My sql server has successfully created all the tables as well.

Now I am trying to implement role based authorisation for my apis for which I created a `usersauth` and a `role` model. This is the code that I am following:

https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-db-example

Configuration.java:

```
//import statements
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersAuthRepository.class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Application.java:

```
  @SpringBootApplication


 public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
 
}
```

When I run my project It gives me this error:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field BlankRepository in 

required a bean of type 


that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 
'BlankRepository' in 
 your 
 configuration.
```

Now this is one of the model that I created previously before implementing authorization. The table is there in sql server as well. It is giving this error after implementing authorisation. I have the required repository for this as well.
I am new at spring boot but I think this error has something to do with the

```
  @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
```

above in my file. Maybe my application is not reading those repos or something. I still dont quite understand the purpose behind this line so can anybody please help me what am i missing?hanks!

Comment: Simply use @EnableJpaRepositories. When you use basePackageClasses, it is only enabling a specific Repository class.

Comment: @SKumar I have tried doing so by using just the annotation but it still gives me this same error

Comment: What is the package name of SecurityConfiguration.java ?

Comment: Try moving @EnableJpaRepositories to SystemyconfigurationApplication

Comment: @SKumar it is ``package risknucleus.systemyconfiguration.rolebasedauth;``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219219/discussion-between-skumar-and-unknown).

Answer (score 0):

add annotatil

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={xxx})
```

or

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Optional<Users> findByName(String username);
}
```

Comment: What am I to add in scanBasePackages? I have a lot of repositories almost 80